# Reconnecting a Mercurial controlled project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

Re-phrased: How can I undo the disconnect?

From the project context menu I choose Team > Disconnect. The .hg files are still in the project folder.
Now I can't figure out how to reconnect my project to the same repo again.

If I choose Team > Reconnect, Eclipse suggests a repo location same as the current local project folder. I have the option to "Create new Mercurial repository at another location..." but if I choose that option, I can not add the repo location I want: "Repository location already known!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disconnect the project. (Team -> Disconnect)
2. Close the project
3. Reopen the project

Answer (score 2):

I just tried doing a disconnect on a project, I could quickly restore it by simply doing: Team->Share, click next on each screen. All the history was correctly restored. Is there something that prevents this?